# Adjoint representation of a Lie group in homology of its lie algebra

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology

It is known that a (Lie) group acts trivially (by identity) in its homology. It is also known that Lie algebra acts trivially (by zero endomorphisms) in its homology. Can we say that a Lie group acts trivially (by identity) in the homology of its Lie algebra if we consider the action induced by adjoint representation?

A reference will be also much appreciated.